# Unable to compile TypeScript: middleware/auth.ts(42,11): error TS2339

Tags: typescript, authentication, backend

## I am trying to put a middleware in my app before logging out and i have face the following error.

## [this is what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4ZUS.png)

## i have tried to put index.d.ts and inside i have putted this

```
import { Request } from "express";
import { IUser } from "../models/user.model";
export { };
declare global {
namespace Express {
interface Request {
user?: IUser;
token?: string;[enter image description here]
>!         }
>!     }
>! }
```